# CSS applied to asp:Label under placeholder1 only working in design view?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

All other parts of css work fine in the browser. This part only works in design view. I tried adding cssclass to it too and clearing cache and running on IE, Chrome and Firefox. Nothing seems to work.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblWelcomeText" runat="server" Text="WELCOME" CssClass="welcome">

.welcome{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    /*border-bottom: 5px solid #f0f1e7;*/
    color: #ffe9da;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 68px;
    font-weight: normal;
    /*line-height: 48px;
    margin: 0 0 26px;
    padding: 0 0 24px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you closed `</asp:Label>` tag.
2. Check the rendered HTML code using Inspect Element tool of your browser, your markup must be like : `<span id="lblWelcomeText" class="welcome">WELCOME</span>`
3. When you inspect the element using the tool you can also check the css applied to the element.
   you can Install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) to your Firefox browser to inspect the element.
   Please update your problem with detail.